# How can I convert string (YYMMDD) to datetime using derived column transformation?

Tags: ssis

I have an input text file, which consists of few columns namely `TransactionID`, `receiveddt`, `description` etc. The `recieveddt` column has date value in the following format **`120419` `(yymmdd)`**. I would like to load the .txt input file into a database but the destination column `recieveddt` is of data type `DateTime`. I used the derived column transformation  to convert the incoming receiveddt column value to datetime as shown below

```
Derived Column Name  Derived Column     Expression            Data Type 
-------------------  -----------------  --------------------  ---------
receiveddate         replace reciveddt  (DT_DATE)[reciveddt]  datetime
```

I tried different combinations but I keep gettings errors while attempting to perform a type cast.

How can I convert string (YYMMDD) to datetime using derived column transformation?

Comment: May i know why dataConversion transformation is not being used?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Expression:

```
(DT_DATE)("20" + SUBSTRING([ReceivedDt], 1, 2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([ReceivedDt], 3, 2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([ReceivedDt], 5, 2))
```

#### For readability:

```
(DT_DATE)("20" + 
    SUBSTRING([ReceivedDt], 1, 2)  + "-" + 
    SUBSTRING([ReceivedDt], 3, 2)  + "-" +
    SUBSTRING([ReceivedDt], 5, 2))
```

#### Cause of the issue:

You cannot convert string in format *`YYMMDD`* to valid date value. Use the above expression to prefix the value with **`20`** to convert the values to format *`YYYYMMDD`* that could be converted to dates.

#### SSIS 2012 package that illustrates the above given expression:

Configure the Data Flow Task with a *OLE DB Source*, *Derived Column Transformation* and two *Multicast Transformations*.

[image: Data Flow Task]

Configure the *OLE DB Source* with the following query that has the values in format *YYMMDD*.

```
SELECT  '120304' AS ReceivedDt UNION
SELECT  '120107' AS ReceivedDt UNION
SELECT  '121211' AS ReceivedDt UNION
SELECT  '121312' AS ReceivedDt;
```

Configure the *Derived Column Transformation* to convert the incoming value in column *ReceivedDt* in format *`YYMMDD`* to *ReceivedDate* of format *`YYYYMMDD`*.

[image: Derived Column Transformation]

Attach data viewer between the Derived Column Transformation and the Multicast Transformations. Configure the Error Output to *Redirect ro*w instead of *Fail component*.

Executing the package will display the string values that could be converted to valid date values in the data viewer between Derived Column Transformation and the success Multicast Transformation.

[image: Success Multicast Transformation]

Executing the package will display the string values that could not be converted to  in the data viewer between Derived Column Transformation and the error Multicast Transformation.

[image: Error Multicast Transformation]

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
(DT_DATE)("20" + SUBSTRING(receivedt,1,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(receivedt,3,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(receivedt,5,2))
```

Note that this conversion assumes that all dates are in the current century. If you have dates in the previous century, you should add a condition to check for that.

Also define an error path for your derived column transformation to catch misformatted dates. You can then, for example, give them a default value.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen for your feedback, it helped me.