# How do I import mm/dd/yyyy values in a file to a database field of format yyyy-mm-dd?

Tags: ssis

I have a CSV file with date column in the following format *mm/dd/yyyy* (4/20/2012), and I  need to load this column into a database that has datetime column in *yyyy-mm-dd* (2012-04-20).

I have used derived column transformation for this purpose and written and expression like

```
(DT_WSTR)(SUBSTRING(ReceivedDateTime,1,4) + "-" + 
SUBSTRING(ReceivedDateTime,5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(ReceivedDateTime,7,2))
```

Upon running my package, it's throwing the error *`Unable to perform type cast`*.

Comment: Try casting it to DT_DBTIMESTAMP instead of DT_WSTR.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the incoming values from the CSV file are always formatted like `04/20/2012` (`MM/DD/YYYY`), then you don't have to perform any type casting. You just have to configure the flat file connection manager to treat the values in the file as `date` data type.

Let's assume that your CSV file looks something like this with a single column containing dates in .

[image: CSV file]

In the SSIS package, create a flat file connection manager to read the CSV file. I stored the CSV in the path `C:\temp\Source.csv`

[image: Flat file source general section]

On the `Advanced` section, you will notice that the flat file connection manager named the first column as `Column1` and the DataType property is set to `string [DT_STR]`. However, the values in the file are actually dates. Either you can manually configure the data types or click on the **`Suggest Types...`** button.

[image: Advanced Suggest Types]

On the *Suggest Column Types*, leave the default values and click *OK*. This will read the first 100 rows of the file and will determine the column type according to the data available in the file.

[image: Suggest column types]

Once you click `OK` on the *Suggest Column Types* dialog, you will notice that the data type on the flat file connection manager for the `Column 0` has been changed to **`date [DT_Date]`**. Click *OK* to configure the flat file connection manager. You can also rename the column according to your requirements (say *InvoiceDate* or *OrderDate* etc.)

[image: Data type changed]

Now that you have the flat file connection manager configured, you can use it inside a Flat file source within a data flow task to read the data and populate your database. So, there is no need to manipulate values using a derived column transformation.

However, if your incoming file values are in string like `120420 (YYMMDD)`, these values cannot be configured as date data types. In these scenarios, you need to use Derived Column transformation as [**suggested in this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10243846/756519).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If your incoming value is a string `20140106(YYYYMMDD)` then typecasting the statement with (`DDT_DBDATE`) will throw an error. I had encountered this issue so I took out the typecast 
and the mapping looked like this:

```
(LEN(TRIM(SUBSTRING([Screening Date],1,8))) > 0 ? (SUBSTRING([Screening Date],1,4) + "/" + SUBSTRING([Screening Date],5,2) + "/" + SUBSTRING([Screening Date],7,2)) : NULL(DT_WSTR,5))
```

Later I added a Data Conversion Transformation and changed it to database timestamp and it worked for me. You can also change it to type date(`DT_DATE`).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, ( I was successful in doing this)

```
(LEN(TRIM(SUBSTRING(ReceivedDateTime,1,8))) > 0 ? (DT_DBDATE)(SUBSTRING(ReceivedDateTime,1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(ReceivedDateTime,5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(ReceivedDateTime,7,2)) : (DT_DBDATE)NULL(DT_WSTR,5))
```

Just typecast the statement with (DT_DBDATE). And this will also serve if there is no date in that position i.e. if the position 1 to 8 of the received string is empty then it will put NULL.